# Find multiple tables with duplicate data in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have many tables in my database. I want to create a general query which will search for duplicate records in all columns of all the tables in a database in SQL server.

Something like this,

```
select 
    T.NAME as TABLE_NAME,
    C.NAME as COLUMN_NAME
from 
    SYS.TABLES as T
inner join 
    SYS.COLUMNS C on T.OBJECT_ID = C.OBJECT_ID
group by 
    T.NAME, C.NAME
having 
    count(*) > 1
```

I do not know how to do it or if there is any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find duplicate column names with something like this:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
group by column_name
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can `join` back to `column` to get the table names.  You might also want to limit the search to base tables (it is unclear what you mean by "duplicates").

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick way to see if two tables are the same you can start with CHECKSUM_AGG and compare the results against two tables. If they have the same columns types and the results of checksum_agg are equal the contents are the same regardless of the row order.